# Typescript error says property does not exist on type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

Note! I have managed to mitigate the problem by using "theme: any" in the below declaration but I would prefer a better approach.

I am using React (v17.0.2) for front-end with material-ui (v5.0.0) and I get the following error:

> Property 'palette' does not exist on type 'Theme'.

whenever I try to access my theme like so:

```
import { useTheme } from '@emotion/react';

export default function MyComponent() {

    const theme = useTheme()

    return (
        <Box
            sx={{
                backgroundColor: theme.palette.mode === 'dark' ? 'primary.dark' : 'primary',
            }}
        ></Box>
    );
}
```

I logged the object with `console.log(theme)` underneath the declaration, and it logged my theme succesfully. So it is there but I cannot access it like shown above.
Here is some of what was logged:

```
{breakpoints: {…}, direction: 'ltr', components: {…}, palette: {…}, spacing: ƒ, …}
  > breakpoints: {keys: Array(5), ...}
  > components: {MuiTypography: {…}, ...}
  direction: "ltr"
  > mixins: {toolbar: {...}}
  > palette: {mode: 'dark', ...}
  ...
```

Also, I found the file where the type "Theme" is located and the property "palette" definitely exists. Here is a snippet of the file:

```
export interface Theme extends SystemTheme {
  mixins: Mixins;
  components?: Components;
  palette: Palette;
  shadows: Shadows;
  transitions: Transitions;
  typography: Typography;
  zIndex: ZIndex;
  unstable_strictMode?: boolean;
}
```

I also tried importing and using Theme like so:

```
import { Theme } from '@mui/material/styles';
...
const theme: Theme = useTheme()
...
```

And this gave me a new error ( underlining the "theme" variable ):

> Type 'Theme' is missing the following properties from type 'Theme': mixins, palette, shadows, transitions, and 6 more.

I tried like this too:

```
import { Theme } from '@mui/material/styles';
...
const theme = useTheme<Theme>()
...
```

And this gave me a new error ( underlining "Theme" in useTheme<**Theme**>() )

> Expected 0 type arguments, but got 1.

and also

> Property 'palette' does not exist on type 'Theme'.

I am new to typescript, so any help is appreciated.

EDIT
Got the answer thanks to Alex Wayne (and maybe also windowsill if I initially misunderstood the answer). Here's the code that worked:

```
import { useTheme, Theme } from '@mui/material';
const theme: Theme = useTheme()
<Box sx={{backgroundColor: theme.palette.mode}}></Box>
```

Comment: Your useTheme and Theme seem to come from different libraries.

Comment: Just tried importing from "@emotion/react" but still got the error that "palette does not exist on type Theme"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- `@emotion/react` exports a `Theme` type, returned by `useTheme()` from the same package.
- `@mui/material/styles` exports a `Theme` type, returned by `createTheme` from the same package.
- These are not the same type.

They have the same name in each package, but are completely unrelated.

This is why this fails:

```
import { useTheme } from '@emotion/react';
import { Theme } from '@mui/material/styles';
const theme: Theme = useTheme()
// Type 'Theme' is missing the following properties from type 'Theme': mixins, palette, shadows, transitions, and 2 more.(2740)
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strictPropertyInitialization=false#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgVwM4FMAqALdJ1wC+cAZlBCHAOQACeEMwEAdgPRToCGAxjFQNwBYAFChIsRHBx4CxMhWo0QyYKxCcY6KME4AbVqhgBPXelQCR3Fobgxc+AFxT7BALwoM0-AAoAlEA)

But this succeeds.

```
import { useTheme, Theme } from '@emotion/react';
const theme: Theme = useTheme()
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strictPropertyInitialization=false#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgVwM4FMAqALdJ0A0cOe6cAvnAGZQQhwDkAAnhDMBAHYD0U6AhgGMYDANwBYAFCCuqeDFz4AXMUVkAvCgwl8ACgCUQA)

I don't know exactly which one you intend to use, but [here are the docs on emotion themes](https://emotion.sh/docs/theming#usetheme) and [here are the docs on Material UI themes](https://mui.com/customization/theming/). They are separate things, and you need to use each according to their intended use.

Comment: I've just tested this but now I get the original error again ```Property 'palette' does not exist on type 'Theme'.```. As an extra note, I have already created a theme and passed it to the ThemeProvider.

Comment: I didn't mean my second snippet is the one you should use. I was merely illustrating the types that are being enforced. If you use `useTheme()` from `@emotion/react` then it will not have a `palette` property because that isn't part of what emotion offers. You seem to be expecting the material UI themeing, so maybe you should follow the documention for that and not use emotion themes at all. Or do themes the emotion way. It's up to you which way to go. But you _cannot_ treat an emotion as a material design theme. They are completely different things.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. Importing the above from "@mui/material" worked.

Answer (score 9):

In order to get proper type checks you can extend emotion Theme interface with MUI's.

```
import { Theme as MuiTheme } from "@mui/material/styles";

declare module '@emotion/react' {
  export interface Theme extends MuiTheme {}
}
```

As specified in
https://emotion.sh/docs/typescript#define-a-theme